# How can I make Rhythmbox start playing a radio stream as I log on?

Tags: 11.04, rhythmbox, banshee

I want to have Rhythmbox start playing a radio stream as soon as I log in. I've tried to run various programs in /usr, including bashnee.desktop, but to no avail.

Answer (score 6):

You can add startup programs by picking `System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications`.  From there, you can add a new entry for Rhythmbox.

For the command line of the new startup application, use `rhythmbox URI` where `URI` refers to the radio stream you want to play.  If you don't know the URI for the radio stream, right click on its entry in Rhythmbox and pick properties.  It should be shown on the details tab.

Answer (score 2):

I use Rhythmbox/Banshee to manage my music collection, but for radio streams I prefer [Radio Tray](http://radiotray.sourceforge.net/), which is extremely simple and useful. Since the version 0.6.2 it can remember the last played station and resume it on startup (using the --resume argument).

Comment: with `radiotray --resume` radiotray tries to load --resume as an URL. Any solutions?